# Why IBM Websphere DataPower?

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am beginer in learning IBM DataPower so please let me know why it is used and 
where it is used and what is the purpose that we use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Datapower is called an appliance because it is purpose built with an OS of its own. The datapower appliance is usually located in the DMZ layer where an organization communicates with the other 3rd party vendor. Datapower has the ability to transform messages as well and the inbuilt security feature makes it a stronghold to secure the DMZ layer. It can connect using many protocols such as MQ, HTTP, HTTPS, JMS, SFTP, FTP, IMS , AS2, AS3 etc as well. It is also used to host APIs and SOAP web services. In short it is used for integrating with application outside of the organization layer.